# <animatemotion> is not working for path when using keySpline attribute

Tags: svg, jquery-animate

I'm trying to use keySpline attribute in order to control the motion of a path describe in SVG, but it doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why.
When the object is described like  or  there are many examples that put an attribute of "values" that control of the coordinates of the shape, but when I'm using path... I'm not sure what to do. Here's my code:

```
<path d="M64.5,17 C69.1944204,17 73,13.1944204 73,8.5 C73,3.80557963 69.1944204,0 64.5,0 C59.8055796,0 56,3.80557963 56,8.5 C56,13.1944204 59.8055796,17 64.5,17 Z" id="right-dot">
                     <animateMotion 
                     path="M0,0 L0,-84.5"
                     dur="1s" 
                     repeatCount="indefinite" 
                     keyTimes="0 ; 0.25 ; 0.5 ; 0.75 ; 1" 
                     keySplines="
                     0.1 0.8 0.3 1;
                     0.1 0.2 0.3 1;
                     0.1 0.8 0.3 1;
                     0.1 0.5 0.3 1;
                     " 
                     calcMode="spline"
                     > 

                </path>
```

Comment: I just checked and it seems to be working as expected on Chrome but not on Safari. Anyway to make it work on Safari?

Comment: try removing the final ; from keySplines

Comment: i can't seem to get it working in chrome. is there an working example anywhere?